# RecyclerView losing state after opening new activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a custom RecyclerView for my app by extending it to my custom class. I use `canScrollVertically(-1)` to check if the RecyclerView can scroll to top before calling `onBackPressed()`. But the problem is after opening new activity to view the full detail on one of the RecyclerView item and press back which will return to the list. The RecyclerView seems to lose the focuse and calling `canScrollVertically` is always true even it is suppose to be false. Do I need to override a method to this custom class?

This is my custom RecyclerView class

```
    public class AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private PublishSubject<Integer> subject;

    private VideoHolder handingVideoHolder;
    private int handlingPosition = 0;
    private int newPosition = -1;

    private int heightScreen;

    public AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);

        Crashlytics.log("AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView");

    }

    public AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    public VideoHolder getHandingVideoHolder() {
        return handingVideoHolder;
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        heightScreen = getHeightScreen(context);
        subject = createSubject();
        addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@androidx.annotation.NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                checkPositionHandingViewHolder();
                subject.onNext(dy);
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkPositionHandingViewHolder() {
        if (handingVideoHolder == null) return;
        Observable.just(handingVideoHolder)
                .map(this::getPercentViewHolderInScreen)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Float>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Float aFloat) {
                        if (aFloat < 50 && handingVideoHolder != null) {
                            handingVideoHolder.stopVideo();
                            handingVideoHolder = null;
                            handlingPosition = -1;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });
    }

    private int getHeightScreen(Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        if (windowManager != null) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        }

        return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    private PublishSubject<Integer> createSubject() {
        subject = PublishSubject.create();
        subject.debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .filter(value -> true)
                .switchMap((Function<Integer, ObservableSource<Integer>>) Observable::just)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::playVideo);
        return subject;
    }

    private void playVideo(float value) {
        Observable.just(value)
                .map(aFloat -> {
                    VideoHolder videoHolder = getViewHolderCenterScreen();
                    if (videoHolder == null) return null;
                    if (videoHolder.equals(handingVideoHolder) && handlingPosition == newPosition)
                        return null;
                    handlingPosition = newPosition;
                    return videoHolder;
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<VideoHolder>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull VideoHolder videoHolder) {
                        if (handingVideoHolder != null) handingVideoHolder.stopVideo();
                        videoHolder.playVideo();

                        handingVideoHolder = videoHolder;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });
    }

    private VideoHolder getViewHolderCenterScreen() {
        int[] limitPosition = getLimitPositionInScreen();
        int min = limitPosition[0];
        int max = limitPosition[1];

        VideoHolder viewHolderMax = null;
        float percentMax = 0;

        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
            if (!(viewHolder instanceof VideoHolder)) continue;
            float percentViewHolder = getPercentViewHolderInScreen((VideoHolder) viewHolder);
            if (percentViewHolder > percentMax && percentViewHolder >= 50) {
                percentMax = percentViewHolder;
                viewHolderMax = (VideoHolder) viewHolder;
                newPosition = i;
            }
        }
        return viewHolderMax;
    }

    private float getPercentViewHolderInScreen(VideoHolder viewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder == null) return 0;
        View view = viewHolder.getVideoLayout();

        int[] location = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        int viewHeight = view.getHeight();
        int viewFromY = location[1];
        int viewToY = location[1] + viewHeight;

        if (viewFromY >= 0 && viewToY <= heightScreen) return 100;
        if (viewFromY < 0 && viewToY > heightScreen) return 100;
        if (viewFromY < 0)
            return ((float) (viewToY - (-viewFromY)) / viewHeight) * 100;
        return ((float) (heightScreen - viewFromY) / viewHeight) * 100;
    }

    private int[] getLimitPositionInScreen() {
        int findFirstVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        int findLastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

        int min = Math.min(Math.min(findFirstVisibleItemPosition, findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition),
                Math.min(findLastVisibleItemPosition, findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition));
        int max = Math.max(Math.max(findFirstVisibleItemPosition, findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition),
                Math.max(findLastVisibleItemPosition, findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition));

        return new int[]{min, max};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
        return super.canScrollVertically(direction);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewCacheExtension(@Nullable ViewCacheExtension extension) {
        super.setViewCacheExtension(extension);
    }

    @Override
    public void setItemViewCacheSize(int size) {
        super.setItemViewCacheSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(int position) {
        super.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your onBackPress() code ?

Comment: I use the predefine onBackPress(), also not missing super call. The issue is not in `onBackPress()` because it is working as intended. The issue is obviously in my custom class that extends RecyclerView that loses the focus after opening new screen. I think it is much better to ask for that code.